# Pass multiple values as parameter into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have the stored procedure to which I pass the parameters. These parameters are indicated by another tool. One of the parameter has a list of entities like `C200`, `C010` etc.

But the requirement is that the person who will run the stored procedure from another tool (Fluence) should be able to call by each entity but also to retrieve the data related to all the entities.

I have the SQL code shown here, which perfectly works if you choose one entity at a time. In the  `Where` clause, I filter it based on the `@Entitygroup` which is `Declared`. From another tool to fetch the all the `Entity` is passed at `Total_group` parameter name.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DW].[SP_Fetch_Data] 
    @par_FiscalCalendarYear varchar(10), 
    @par_Entity AS varchar (10)
AS
BEGIN
    /*
    BALANCE ACCOUNTS
    */
    DECLARE @FiscalCalendarYear int  =  SUBSTRING(@par_FiscalCalendarYear,1,4)  /* 2022 */
        , @FiscalCalendarMonth int =  SUBSTRING (@par_FiscalCalendarYear,7,10) /* 11 */;
    DECLARE @FiscalCalendarPeriod int = @FiscalCalendarYear * 100 + @FiscalCalendarMonth
    DECLARE @Entitygroup varchar = @par_Entity
    
    SELECT UPPER([GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId) as [Entity]
        , CONCAT(@FiscalCalendarYear, ' P', @FiscalCalendarMonth) as [Date]
        , ISNULL(ConsolidationMainAccount, '') as [Account]
        , [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].TransactionCurrencyCode as [Currency]
        , SUM([GeneralJournalAccountEntry].TransactionCurrencyAmount) as [Amount]
        , 'Import' as [Audit]
        , 'TCUR' as [DataView]
        , ISNULL([CostCenter].[GroupDimension], 'No Costcenter') as [CostCenter]
        , 'No Group' as [Group]
        , ISNULL([Intercompany].[DisplayValue], 'No Intercompany') as [Intercompany]
        , 'Closing' as [Movement]
        , ISNULL([ProductCategory].[GroupDimension], 'No ProductCategory')  as [ProductCategory]
        , ISNULL([Region].[GroupDimension], 'No Region')  as [Region]
        , ISNULL([SalesChannel].[GroupDimension], 'No SalesChannel')  as [SalesChannel]
        , 'Actual' as [Scenario]
    FROM [D365].[GeneralJournalAccountEntry]
    LEFT JOIN [D365].[GeneralJournalEntry] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].GENERALJOURNALENTRY = [GeneralJournalEntry].[RECID]
        AND [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[PARTITION] = [GeneralJournalEntry].[PARTITION]
    LEFT JOIN [D365].[FiscalCalendarPeriod] ON [GeneralJournalEntry].FiscalCalendarPeriod = FiscalCalendarPeriod.FiscalCalendarPeriod
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[MainAccounts] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].MainAccount = [MainAccounts].[RECID]
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[Intercompany] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[RECID] = [Intercompany].[RECID]
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[ProductCategory] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[RECID] = [ProductCategory].[RECID]
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[Region] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[RECID] = [Region].[RECID]
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[SalesChannel] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[RECID] = [SalesChannel].[RECID]
    LEFT JOIN [DW].[CostCenter] ON [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].[RECID] = [CostCenter].[RECID]
    WHERE [EnumItemName] IN ('Revenue', 'Expense', 'BalanceSheet', 'Asset', 'Liability')
    AND [FiscalCalendarPeriod].FiscalCalendarPeriodInt <= @FiscalCalendarPeriod
    AND [GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId <= @Entitygroup
    GROUP BY UPPER([GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId)
        , ISNULL(ConsolidationMainAccount, '')
        , [GeneralJournalAccountEntry].TransactionCurrencyCode
        , ISNULL([CostCenter].[GroupDimension], 'No Costcenter')
        , ISNULL([Intercompany].[DisplayValue], 'No Intercompany')
        , ISNULL([ProductCategory].[GroupDimension], 'No ProductCategory')
        , ISNULL([Region].[GroupDimension], 'No Region')
        , ISNULL([SalesChannel].[GroupDimension], 'No SalesChannel')
```

Comment: Why are you `LEFT JOIN`ing to `FiscalCalendarPeriod` when `FiscalCalendarPeriodInt` *must* have a non-`NULL` value? It's impossible for `FiscalCalendarPeriodInt` to have a non-`NULL` value is no related row was found.

Comment: What is your question here exactly as well, you don't really ask anything. Your title asks how to pass multiple values; do you mean the procedure needs multiple parameters? Then just define those: `@parameter1 date, @parameter2 varchar(20), ...`. If you mean you want a single parameter to have multiple values, use a table type parameter.

Comment: My question is how can I pass as parameter one specific `Entity` and also `All entity` at the same time. So user can choos to retire one specific `Entity` data or all

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I know I know, from another post, but first Ill fix this and then Ill change name. Thanks for remining me

Comment: *"My question is how can I pass as parameter one specific `Entity` and also `All entity` at the same time."* How can something have 2 different values at the same time? SQL Server doesn't support quantum states.

Comment: what if I put this in my `WHERE` clasue  `AND ([GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId = @Entitygroup
  OR 'Total_Group' = @Entitygroup)`

Answer (score 0):

(would be a mess as a comment)

Do you mean if @par_entity is not null and has a value other than '' then use that else go on as if it is not there at all? Then you can change your code:

```
DECLARE @Entitygroup varchar = @par_Entity
```

To:

```
DECLARE @Entitygroup varchar = case 
             when @par_Entity is not null then @par_Entity 
             else '' 
           end;
```

And:

```
AND [GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId <= @Entitygroup
```

To:

```
AND (@Entitygroup = '' OR [GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId <= @Entitygroup)
```

PS: Performance wise it wouldn't be optimal.

EDIT: You might also set it to the possible max value when it is not passed. ie:

```
DECLARE @Entitygroup varchar = case 
                 when @par_Entity is null or @par_entity = '' then 'zzzzzz' 
                 else @par_Entity
               end;

AND [GeneralJournalEntry].SubledgerVoucherDataAreaId <= @Entitygroup
```